# Correlation Distance Metric and Sum of Squared Errors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, metrics, biopython

I couldn't find a way with scikit-learn, to use the correlation distance metric on K-Means - it is necessary for my genes expression dataset.

But when searching the internet, I found this great library: [biopython](https://biopython.org/wiki/Download) - which has the ability to use the correlation distance metric on K-Means.

However, unlike scikit-learn, I cannot get the inertia / sum of squared errors, and therefore I cannot make a choice of the optimal number of K (clusters) using the 'Elbow Method' (there is only an option to get the "error" value which is the "within-cluster sum of distances" - not squared!): https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Cluster.html

How can I do both: use correlation distance metric **and** get the SSE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of squared error is more easily implemented than the correlation distance metric, so I would advise you to use biopython together with the following helper function. It should compute the sum of squared errors for you from the data (assumed to be a numpy array) and biopython's `clusterid` output.

```
def SSE(data, clusterid):
    """
    Computes the sum of squared error of the data classification.
    
    Arguments:
        data: nrows x ncolumns array containing the data values.
        clusterid: array containing the number of the cluster to which each item was assigned by biopython.
    """
    
    number_of_classes = int(clusterid.max()) + 1 #Python convention: first index is 0
    
    sse = 0.0
    for i in range(number_of_classes):
        cluster = data[clusterid==i]
        sse += cluster.std(ddof=len(cluster)-1)**2
    return sse
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer and for the written code!
If I indeed use your additional SSE function, the calculation of the SSE will be made on the original dataset, instead of the dataset that has been created "off-scene" with the correlation-distance metric (which is a dataset that cannot be seen practically when using the bio-python's clustering function).
Wouldn't it cause the SSE's to possibly have unequal deviations from their values using the correlation-distance metric?

Comment: Furthermore, for some reason when I used your function, the values of the SSE's increased along with the increase of the number of K clusters. Shouldn't it behave differently? – Shouldn't the SSE's decrease as the value of K clusters increase?

Comment: I cannot answer your first question, but I am very surprised by the behavior you describe. Indeed, the SSE should decrease when the number of clusters increases (and, if there are as as many clusters as data points, the SSE should be 0). Can you post more details (like the SSE as a function of the number of clusters for example)?

Comment: I cannot obtain the exact function of the SSE by number of clusters, but the visual graph that I made, using your function above, showed this weird relation that I described. With your function, the graph turned out to be somehow more similar to the silhouette method. Eventually, I solved this entire problem by implementing the correlation distance metric and used the regular known scikit-learn functions, which was quite annoying, but still worked... Thank you very much for all of your help and efforts!

Comment: And as for my first question, I was practically creating a dataset with the correlation distance metric and calculated its SSE. Apparently, that was the right thing to do: when I calculated the SSE with the original dataset (without the correlation-distance metric) I got some massive deviations and the clustering process became a huge mess :)